Calculator For Mathematical Sequence
I'm wanting to calculate a mathematical sequence of adding (54.5782*0.99997105^n) (in which n increases by 1 each time) (until n reaches 436,422).
That looks like
((54.5782*0.99997105^1)+(54.5782*0.99997105^2)+(54.5782*0.99997105^3)+(54.5782*0.99997105^4)...).

What resource could I use to calculate that?
I've been searching the internet for any resource that could possibly do that for a long time, but I wasn't able to find any. I haven't yet explored something like ChatGPT (which I have never used before).
Thanks!

Why couldn't you use the formula for geometric series?

As an FYI: ChatGPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations (more). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "hallucinate" fake facts. Some extra examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Your goal is to calculate
$$
\sum_{k=L}^U ar^k
$$
where

$L=1$ (lower bound of the sum)
$U=436422$ (upper bound of the sum)
$a=54.578$
$r=0.99997105$ (common ratio)
$\sum_{k=L}^U f(k)$ means $f(L) + f(L+1) + f(L+2) + \cdots + f(U)$

This is a geometric series, hence the choice to frame this generically. It is well known that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}
$$
(To prove this, let the summation be $S$, and find $rS-S$.) Some basic manipulations will suffice to find the answer for the more generic series I started with from there; I'll leave those details to you.

If you just want the answer to your specific scenario, and not a general formula, WolframAlpha will suffice and tell you it is $\approx 1.8851897130538702 \times 10^6$.
If you need a more exact answer, then you may need to pursue some sort of coding approach in lieu of online tools.
